# Weird behavior of the overflow-x property

Tags: css

Can anyone explain me what is going on here. I specify that overflow-x should be visible and I get horizontal scrollbar. Why is this happening? Am I missing something or should I get some sleep?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cssGuy/6j5057my/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<p id="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit corporis est esse provident assumenda consequatur vel atque minima id veritatis! Totam iure omnis laudantium provident dolorum blanditiis modi voluptatibus nihil.</p>
<p id="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum tempore debitis blanditiis iure aperiam quam vero esse perferendis doloremque eos natus nemo quos mollitia ratione qui laboriosam itaque animi tempora.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* DIFFERENCE BETWEEN WIDTH:AUTO & WIDTH:100% */
* {margin: 0;padding: 0;}
#container {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: visible;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
#one {
    width: auto;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 20px;
    border:10px solid gray;
}
#two {
    width: 100%;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 20px;
    border:10px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: what is your expected output..?

Comment: The expected output should be overflow:visible on x-axis but I get scroll-bar, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

So you specify to always show scroll bar for x-axis. Use `overflow-x: auto` to show scroll bar only when needed.

Comment: No I don't want scroll bar, I need my parapgraph to spill out my container and there should not be any scroll bars on x-axis as I declared overflow-x: visible.

Comment: That's not what overflow-x does. overflow-x is for the scrollbar

Comment: I think you're confusing `overflow-x: visible` with `overflow-x: scroll` there, Steve.

Comment: I know all that :) What bothers me is the behavior of overflow-x property which I set to be visible on x-axis, so that means that there should not be any scroll bars on horizontal axis, right ?

Comment: I don't really understand why it doesn't work. I do know however that by fiddling with your JSFiddle, it's working as intended as soon as I remove the `overflow-y: hidden` line. Apparently the overflow-y interacts with the overflow-x somehow.

Comment: Yes just wanted to say that, when you remove overflow-y it works the way I want. that is so wierd

Comment: A quick google turned up this reference page: [http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html). Apperently it's just a combination that's not possible. You might be able to trick it by adding an extra container and putting the `overflow-y: hidden` on that one, if you absolutely have to have it.

Comment: It seems the page is down for me :/

Comment: Weird, it's working fine for me. But let me link you the relevant W3C page then [http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x). If you scroll down to the text below Example XX it mentions specific rules for the "visible" value. For some reason it doesn't mention the combination with "hidden", but it works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change width of the second 'p' tag to auto and change overflow-x: auto.

```
#container {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: green;
}
#one {
    width: auto;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 20px;
    border:10px solid gray;
}
#two {

    width: auto;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 20px;
    border:10px solid gray;
}
```

Look at here: http://jsfiddle.net/6j5057my/1/